# SingleChildScrollView show white

Tags: flutter

i need to fix overflowed pixel, but when i use `SingleChildScrollView`, it just show white screen

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body:
       Container(
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(flex:5, child: Textselamatdatang(), ),
              Flexible(flex:4, child: 
              Container(
                    child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Loginformcontrainer(),
                      SizedBox(height: 30,),
                      Loginbutton()
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ) ),
            ],
      ),
         ),
       ),
      ); 
  }
```

Comment: remove `Container` From SingleChildScrollView use `body:SingleChildScrollView(child:Column)` ,also remove `flex` from `Flexible`@AiHaQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for your `Flexibles` Widgets . In `SingleChildScrollView` you should define height for objects and you can't use Expanded or Flexible Widget.
I removed Your Flexible Widgets and your code works fine

Comment: Yes, in my ui design, I place form and button in bottom, now i use `mediaquery` in `Textselamatdatang()`and that works, thank you

Comment: Instead of SingleChildScrollView you can use Column and in Column use ListView and wrap it with Expanded Widget to get max height as it can. then your form and button go to bottom of screen. I send you the pattern of code and I edit my answer.

Comment: I still new in flutter, thanks, used expanded widget more better